# Raster data projection without spatial reference

Tags: raster, coordinate-system

I have hundred raster data without spatial reference on it. (Spatial Reference is undefined and xY coordinate system is unknown)

The original raster data was Subdataset so I used 'Data Management tools\Raster\Raster ProcessingExtract Subdataset' to extract the single raster.

Now, I think I have to define the projection so I can make a mosaic data from raster file. 
I have a point shape file which indicate the middle of the raster data. 
I also have to rotate the raster data as well.

What is the best way to do this process?
I tried geo-reference however I have more than 100 files to process so I will like to use ArcMap tool or GDal or Python.

Comment: If you only have one point for each raster file then you are stuck. However if your rasters tile perfectly with no gaps or overlaps then you can work out the locations of all four corners of your rasters. Do they tile perfectly?

Comment: It looks like every point shows the middle point of the raster. There are lots of field in shape file which I don't recognize at all. I think I can calculates four corner of raster with cell size and columns and row information.

Comment: And raster data overlapped each other.

Comment: Are the original rasters georeferenced or not? That is, if you check the extent are the values the cells totals or do they look like geographic or projected coordinates? If the latter, try posting a sample extent plus the general location of the raster (city, administrative district, lat/lon) and maybe someone can identify it.

Comment: Unless you can figure out what the fields in the shapefile are, or find some other metadata to describe the location then the only technique I can think of would be some automated way of matching your rasters with some other raster, but without knowing what your rasters look like (are they RGB images, elevation, or some other sensor data) or what metadata you have I think we're stuck.